# NGINX server is downloading php files

Tags: php, nginx

i'm trying to setup nginx on my vps and i made it however when i'm try to use .php files it download then instead of runing them. This is my nginx.conf

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name site;
     root /var/www/;
     index index.php index.html;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?
(i have php5-fpm installed)

Comment: check `/etc/php5/fpm/pools.d/www.conf` and search for a line that starts with `listen`, what does it say ( ignore commented lines )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to enable php-cgi/fast-cgi or -cli depending on your server/vps configuration.

share with us more information to be able to help you (like config files etc.)

Comment: follow the post of @Slava underneeth and be sure that you have installed the php version you need using your distribution's package manager.

Answer (score 2):

For pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI you must add this into server config:

```
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```